# cmake error: file INSTALL cannot find "AUTHORS": no error

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to build this repository using the latest CMake GUI and Visual Studio 2019:
https://github.com/cginternals/openll

After building and linking all the dependencies I get no errors in CMake, also building the solution in VS2019 works without any issues, however, when building the install target I get the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 149
```

and the following output:

```
4>CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:44 (file):
4>  file INSTALL cannot find
4>  "C:/Users/Johannes/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/AUTHORS": No
4>  error.
4>
4>
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
4>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In my build folder the referenced part of the file `cmake_install.cmake` looks like this (these are lines 35 to 57):

```
if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xruntimex" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE FILE FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/build/VERSION")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xdevx" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE FILE FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/openll-config.cmake")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xruntimex" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE FILE FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/AUTHORS")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xruntimex" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE FILE FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/LICENSE")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xruntimex" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE FILE FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/README.md")
endif()

if("x${CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT}x" STREQUAL "xruntimex" OR NOT CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT)
  file(INSTALL DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/." TYPE DIRECTORY FILES "C:/Users/user/source/repos/CGInternals/openll/ll-opengl/data")
endif()
```

What does this mean? There is no file named "AUTHORS" neither in the source nor in the build folder. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Since the cmake file describes AUTHORS as a project meta file, and since it goes along with README.md and LICENSE (which do exist) perhaps the best solution would be to create a placeholder version of this file. You could even include yourself as an author!

Comment: @john hmm, thanks I'll give that a try!

Comment: @john OK, I simply created an empty file AUTHORS and added it into the folders, I also got the same error again with README and LICENSE, which where in the repos base folder not in "II-opengl", which I have used as the source folder for CMAKE. I suspect this was also the general problem, however I had to select this folder as source, since it contains the cmake configuration files.
Anyway, now the install project built without errors, so it should be all good. Thanks again!